# gnuplot plot a column versus integers numbers

Tags: plot, gnuplot, using

I know that to plot two columns one versus the other I have to use:
plot "datafile.dat" using 1:2
but what if I have just one column in my datafile and I want to plot it by associating each value to an integer number starting from 0, that is, my column in the datafile will be the y-axis and the integer numbers will be the x-axis

I appreciate your help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that is to use the `0` pseudocolumn:

```
plot 'datafile.dat' u 0:1
```

Easy!  :)

I recommend looking up pseudocolumns in the gnuplot documentation as well as the details of the `using` command; there are lots of other useful manipulations possible.